# Prolog - Returning a List from a Recursive Predicate

Tags: list, prolog

I am using GNU-Prolog, and I have the following code that finds the numbers less than X which are divisible by Y. Assume X and Y > 0.

```
find_num(X, Y) :-
     findall(N, between(1,X,N), List),
     check_list(List, Y).

check_list([Head|Tail], Y) :-
    ( 
        divides(Head, Y) ->
            format('~w ~s ~w ~n', [Head, "divisible by", Y]);
        true
    ),

check_list(Tail, Y).

divides(X, Y) :-
    X mod Y =:= 0.
```

The code outputs a text for the numbers, but I want the result to be a list like X = [1,2,3].

I tried multiple ways to make the list, but didn't succeed, examples:

```
check_list([Head|Tail], Y) :-
( 
    divides(Head, Y) ->
        findall( X, determine_item(Head, X), List );
    true
),

check_list(Tail, Y).
```

or

```
find_num(X, Y) :-
    findall(N, between(1,X,N), List),
    findall(N, check_list(List, Y, N), List2),
    write(List2).

check_list([Head|Tail], Y, _) :-
    ( 
        divides(Head, Y) ->
            Head;
        true
    ),
    check_list(Tail, Y).

divides(X, Y) :-
    X mod Y =:= 0.
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: `findall(I, ( between(1,X,I), I mod Y =:= 0 ), List)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want a list, your `find_num` (and your `check_list`) needs a third argument so...

What about

```
divides(X, Y) :-
    X mod Y =:= 0.

find_num(X, Y, Lout) :-
     findall(N, between(1, X, N), Lin),
     check_list(Lin, Y, Lout).

check_list([], _, []).

check_list([H | Tin], Y, [H | Tout]) :-
  divides(H, Y),
  check_list(Tin, Y, Tout).

check_list([H | Tin], Y, Lout) :-
  \+ divides(H, Y),
  check_list(Tin, Y, Lout).
```

?

Comment: I was wondering if you could explain the code a little. I'm very new to Prolog, and have found that this code is suitable for what I would like to do, but I would love to learn a little more about what is going on in the code please. Thank you in advance.